# Regex - match a string not contain a 'semi-word'

Tags: regex, notepad++

I tried to make regex syntax for that but I failed.

I have 2 variables

PlayerInfo[playerid][pLevel]
and
Character[playerid]

and I want to catch only the second variable,I mean only the world what don't contain PlayerInfo, but cointains [playerid]

`"(\S+)\[playerid\]"` cath both words and `(\S+[^PlayerInfo])\[playerid\]` jump on some variables- they contais p,l,a,y ...

I need to replace in notepad++,all variables like **Text[playerid]** to ExClass **[playerid][Text]**

Comment: Can you please format your question properly? I'm not sure what to make of it. http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Very confusing question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple Pluasible solutions.

List item

1. Notepad has a plugin called [python script.](http://npppythonscript.sourceforge.net/)  Running regex from there
   gives full regex functionality, the python version anyway, and a lot
   of powerful potential beyond that.  And I use the [online python regex tester](http://re-try.appspot.com/) to help out.
2. RegRexReplace plugin helps create regex plugins in Notepad++, so when you do hit a limitation, you find out a lot quicker.
3. Or of course default to your alternate editor (I'm assuming you have
   one?) or this online [regex tool](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) is absolutely amazing.  You
   can perform the action on the text online as well.

(I'd try to build a regex for you, but I'm a bit lost as to what you're looking for.  Unless the Ivo Abeloos got it.  If you're still coming up short, maybe a code example along with values displayed?)
Good luck!

Comment: Regex tool from no.3 does not support regex lookahead. [Regex Tester](http://www.regextester.com/) is better.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Notepad++ support negative lookbehind since v6.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use negative lookbehind.

```
(?<!PlayerInfo)\[playerid\]
```

**EDIT**: unfortunately notepad++ does not support negative lookbehind.

I tried to make a workaround based on the following naive idea:

(.[^o]|[^f]o)[playerid]

But this expression does not work either. Notepad++ seems to fail in alternative operator. Thus the answer is: it is impossible to do exactly what you want. Try to solve the problem in other way or use alternative tool.

Comment: Nope, Notepad++ doesn't support that.

Comment: v6+ supports negative look-behind

Answer (score 0):

In notepad++ you could try to replace `(.+)\[(.+)\]` with `ExClass\[\2\]\[\1\]`