# Notepad++ Regular Expression : Find all input tags without ID, add if missing

Tags: jquery, regex, notepad++

I have lot of html files that have been developed with Input tag without ID and have only name to identify the object via javascript.

Using notepad++ regular expression find and replace, can anyone help me find all input tags with missing ID and insert it with value same as "name" , leaving rest of the elements as it is

```
<input name="MyName" MyAttr="3453" >
```

replace to

```
<input name="MyName" id="MyName" MyAttr="3453" >
```

Would like to do this with Notepad++ or if you know of any other editor which can do bulk operation.

Can anyone help me please ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What FailedDev says seems right to me.  If the order of the tags is consistent then you may be able to match based on that, but if the tags are reordered then you may need to use a more sophisticated RegEx tool.

Comment: Are *all* the `input`s missing an `id` attribute? Or just some of them?

Comment: Some of them are missing. Some have extra attributes too. That makes it more tricky.

Answer (score 2):

```
(<input.*?(?!.*\bid=['"]))(?=>)
```

Replace with :

```
$1id="MyName"
```

The above regular expression would work fine were you using perl or other utilities which support PCRE expressions. Notepad ++ however does not support this : http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Regular_Expressions

So I am afraid that this is not possible to do with notepad ++

Answer (score 1):

***Warning:*** [Regular Expressions are not the best way to find things in HTML files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677038/how-to-use-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-in-java).

The metacharacters used to delimit HTML tags can also show up in other places in the file, and it is not possible to write a regular expression to handle all the possible cases.

Unless your HTML files are very simple, you are better off writing a program using an HTML parser. There are many parsers available for Java and .NET.

Comment: I think the original poster was trying to do some quick cleanup of a static file in Notepad++, not write a .NET or Java app.

Comment: @David, he asked for either notepad or another bulk editor that could work. Writing simple apps should not be too far out of the question for a StackOverflow poster. Otherwise he should be asking on SuperUser instead.

Comment: My initial intention was a quick cleanup avoiding to write parser myself. Next quick solution that I will try is using python addon with Notepad++ [PythonScript](http://npppythonscript.sourceforge.net/), that I read on link posted by Faildev. Thanks guys for your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

[FaildDev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996123/notepad-regular-expression-find-all-input-tags-without-id-add-if-missing/7996325#7996325) gave the correct answer: The default Notepad++ regex engine just isn't up to the task.

However, you can look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941006/regex-match-a-string-not-contain-a-semi-word) for some tips on making this work by extending Notepad++, as well as links to alternatives.

Also, here is an updated regex that allows you to use the name value as your id which is, I think, what you were asking:

```
(<input.+?name="(\w+)")((?:(?!id=).)*?>)
```

Replace with:

```
$1 id="$2"$3
```

You can try it out online using [REGex TESTER](http://www.regextester.com/). Note that it is not incredibly robust, but if you know that the HTML you are running it on is fairly consistent you should be able to get away with it.